# How to display an array of images as a list and make them clickable to display some text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, for-loop

I need to display a list of images from an array and also make it clickable to display some text on click. Looking for some simple solution only with javascript.

```
var images = ["img1", "img2", "img3"];

var allPics = images.length;
var i = 0;

for(;i<allPics; i++){
myImg.src = images[i];
}
```

Example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gmqLtd1u/1/

Now only one image is displayed.

Comment: On each iteration of your loop, you're not creating a new `img` tag, but rather just updating the source for the `img` tag `myImg` with the current image in the iteration. That's why your last image is the image that is displayed. What have you tried to do to resolve this? You also haven't asked a question yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now only one image is displayed.

Because you're using one `<img>` and update its `src` several times in loop. After last iteration, its `src` is not updated anymore. That's why you see the last image.

Change your html, so that instead of `<img>` you have `<div>` as container/placeholder:

```
<!-- <img id="myImg"/> -->

<div id="myImg"></div>
```

And change your JS, to create `<img>` and append it to `<div>`:

```
for(;i<allPics; i++){
    // myImg.src = images[i];

    // TODO: adjust this to whatever you want
    // in this example, use `<a>` that link to another page
    // you can use javascript to show modal/alert too
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'example.html'; // TODO: adjust this

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = images[i];
    a.appendChild(img);

    document.getElementById('myImg').appendChild(a);
}
```

And maybe your CSS, to match with new output:

```
#myImg img {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Alvin.

Comment: If i have an array of videos just like i have of images and i need to play video when image is clicked. How i can link videos array with images array?

Comment: you can use the combination of html & js. first, display your video and give it unique id (eg: <video id"video1"><source src="..."></video>), then display image and add js to play video when clicked (eg: <img src="..." onclick="document.getElementById('video1').play()">). the idea is the same as before, you just need to adjust the output. for unique id, you can use array index.

Comment: thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. Please I need little help again. Actually i don't want all the videos displayed on the page. I have an school assignment in which i have list of videos and list of images. In header i have one video and list of images in footer. When i click image it should hide first video and play another video linked to image.
EX:       var img=['img1', 'img2', 'img3'];  
and.. .   var video=['vid1', 'vid2', vid3];
now if i click on img1 then vid1 should play.

Comment: thank you so much. I really appreciate your help but i think i was unable to explain you in proper way, i have 2 arrays one is images and one is videos. If i click on img[1] then it should play video[1].